# Moq mock generic class

Tags: c#, .net, moq

Having the following in my code:

```
var contact = m_someFactory.Create<IContact>(contact, Page.ID);
```

code from Factory:

ObjectFactory implements AbstractFactory

```
    ObjectsFactory : AbstractFactory
{
    public T Create<T>()
    {
        var factory = this as IInsertFactoryMethod<T>;
        return factory != null
            ? factory.Create()
            : default(T);
    }
```

I want to be able to mock this.
I've created a class that implements IContact

```
public class Contact{
      public Name {get; set;}  
      IOrganization Organization { get; set; }
}
```

For setup I tried this:

```
FactoryMock = new Mock<ObjectsFactory>();
FactoryMock.Setup(x => x.Create<IContact>()).Returns(new Mock<IContact>().Object);
```

and this

```
FactoryMock.Setup(x => x.Create<IContact>(null, It.IsAny<int>())).Returns(new Mock<IContact>().Object);
```

During the setup I get the following:

> Additional information: Invalid setup on a non-virtual (overridable in
>   VB) member: x => x.Create()

What am I doing wrong?

UPDATE:
In my code I have the following:

```
    var contact = m_someFactory.Create<IContact>(contact, Page.ID);
var organization = contact.Organization;
```

How would I set this up if Organization is an interface in Contact?

Comment: You can't `Setup` a method that isn't virtual.  Here, `Factory.Create` is not marked as `virtual`.

Comment: if I add "virtual" to that method, would that setup work?

Comment: Yep.  However, you're generally better off mocking interfaces rather than concretes, this being one reason why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[You can't `Setup` a method that isn't virtual in Moq](https://moq.uservoice.com/forums/11304-general/suggestions/1329275-support-mocking-non-virtual-method-and-sealed-clas). Here, `Factory.Create` is not marked as virtual.

Changing the signature of `Create` to make it virtual will allow the mock to work as you're intending it, but you're generally better off mocking interfaces rather than concretes.  This demonstrates one reason why: you're changing your implementation to make it testable for your testing framework.

Comment: That worked. however I get another issue. can you please see my edit above

Comment: Make a different question for that, that's unrelated to this one.

Comment: I did here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35302816/moq-an-interface-property-of-a-class