# Moq an interface property of a class

Tags: c#, .net, moq

Having the following:

```
var contact = m_someFactory.Create<IContact>(contact, Page.ID);
var organization = contact.Organization;
```

I need to mock someFactory as well as Organization interface.

I've tried this but contact comes back null. I want to set contact to whatever and contact.Organization to anything but not null IOrganization:

```
    var organizationMock = new Mock<IOrganization>();
    ObjectFactoryMock.Setup(x => x.Create<IContact>()).Returns(new ContactFake{ Organization = organizationMock.Object });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set up the method with the same parameters:

```
 ObjectFactoryMock.Setup(x => x.Create<IContact>(It.IsAny<T>,It.IsAny<T>)).Returns(new ContactFake{ Organization = organizationMock.Object });
```

But replace the T's with the types of contact and page.id

See https://github.com/Moq/moq4/wiki/Quickstart#matching-arguments